# Is it true that $\alpha\mu_1 + (1-\alpha)\mu_2 < \mu_2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-verification

Can we prove that : $$\alpha\mu_1 + (1-\alpha)\mu_2 < \mu_2.$$ Given that : $$ \alpha \in [0,1]  $$ and $$ \mu_1 < \mu_2. $$
Is the statement true at all?

Comment: It's false for $\alpha=0$, as both sides are equal to $\mu_2$.

Comment: If $\alpha >0$ strictly, then $\alpha \mu_1 + (1-\alpha)\mu_2 < \alpha \mu_2 + (1-\alpha)\mu_2=\mu_2$.

Comment: What *is* true is that $\,\mu_1 \le \alpha \mu_1 + (1-\alpha) \mu_2 \le \mu_2\,$. For *strict* inequalities you need to restrict $\alpha$ to the *open* interval $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\alpha>0$ we need to prove that $$\alpha\mu_1 + \mu_2-\alpha\mu_2 < \mu_2$$ or
$$\alpha(\mu_1-\mu_2)<0$$ or
$$\mu_1<\mu_2,$$
which is given.

But for $\alpha=0$ we obtain
$$\mu_2<\mu_2,$$ which is wrong.

Comment: You could indicate that $\alpha$ should be larger than $0$.

Comment: @Scientifica I fixed. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :)